# Enhanced dissipation for Kolmogorov flow

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis

My problem is  $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\ sin(y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2})$$ 
with periodic boundary conditions and initial conditions $$u(x,y,0)=\sin x$$

I want to check  if the 
L^2 norm of the solution behaves like this $$|u|2_{L^2} =(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u^2 dx dy)^{1/2} \leq e^{-\sqrt{\nu} t}$$

I don't have the exact solution is it possible to tell if we get closer to the exact solution or not ?
Using fourier collocation method 
plotting the solution in case $\nu =.04$
[image]

trying to plot the $L^2 $ norm and compare it with $e^{- 0.2 t}$

However it might not be true due to the constant

[image]

Comment: In order to check that the inequality you stated is satisfied my approach would be to square both sides, and differentiate both sides with respect to $t$, and then use both the PDE and the initial condition to prove that it's satisfied or not.